# SimpleForm + Carrierwave - Image upload not saving properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, simple-form

I am building a Rails app where I need users to upload a profile image on the registration form/have an image edit feature for profile photo. Carrierwave should be properly installed and so far Devise seems to be running fine. When I go to upload the photo and then click "Create Profile", it simply refreshes to the same page and resets the file upload field each time.

SOLUTION: Updated update method in controller to:

```
 def update
   @pet = Pet.find(params[:id])

 if @pet.update(pet_params)
    redirect_to pets_path
 else
     render :edit
   end
 end
```

It's uploaded in my app/uploaders/profile_photo_uploader.rb file:

```
 class ProfilePhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
 end
```

I have a "profile_photo" string in my schema, as well.

And my controller actions for create and edit/update are here:

```
 def create
   @pet = Pet.new(pet_params)

   if @pet.save
     flash[:notice] = 'Your pet profile was saved!'
     redirect_to pets_path
   else
     flash.now[:notice] = 'Your pet profile could not be saved.'
     render :new
   end
 end

 def show
   @pet = Pet.find(params[:id])
 end

 def edit
   @pet = Pet.find(params[:id])
 end

 def update
   @pet = Pet.find(params[:id])

   if @pet.save
     redirect_to pets_path
   else
     render :edit
   end
 end

 def pet_params
   params.require(:pet).permit(:name, :breed, :age,
     :color, :weight, :personality, :favorite_things, :owner_id, :profile_photo)
 end
```

My new form using SimpleForm:

```
<h1>New Pet Profile</h1>

<%= simple_form_for @pet, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, required: true, label: "Pet Name:"  %>
  <%= f.input :profile_photo, type: :file %>
                   ...
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
   devise_for :owners

   resources :pets

   resources :owners do
     resources :pets, shallow: true
   end
 end
```

Application Controller:

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   protect_from_forgery with: :exception

   before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

   protected

   def configure_permitted_parameters
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :profile_photo
   end
 end
```

Comment: Could you expand upon the error you're getting?

Comment: I'm not even getting an error, per se. The File Upload button works as far as allowing me to select a photo, but once I go to submit my registration form it doesn't save the photo. It just fails to save the form, redirects to the same page and the file upload "field" is empty even though the other previously filled out form fields are saved.

Comment: You create the pets resource twice.  That's a conflict in your routes http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting

Answer (score 1):

You need to have  your model set `app/models/pet.rb` with

```
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :profile_photo
  belongs_to :owner
  mount_uploader :profile_photo, ProfilePhotoUploader
end
```

Also, side note, if you're using Heroku it won't save pictures since it's a static service.  You need to integrate a service like Cloudinary with Carrierwave.

---

After your form line `<%= simple_form_for @pet, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>` put this in

```
<% if @pet.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@pet.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this pet from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @pet.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
```

and this line `<%= f.input :profile_photo, type: :file %>` to this `<%= f.file_field :profile_photo %>`

---

At the end of your pet_controller's file make sure you've given permission for the form to submit the data

```
def pet_params
  params.require(:pet).permit(:name, :profile_photo)
end
```

---

Since I see you're using devise you might consider assigning the owner to the pet.  Consider the line in your `pet_controller.rb`

```
def create
  @pet = Pet.new(pet_params)
  @pet.owner = current_user
```

And see the line in model `belongs_to :owner`

Comment: Alright, I set that model up and restarted my server, but am still having the same issue. For now I am just saving my photo locally since it's a school project, but will eventually be pushing it up to Heroku so I'll certainly have to customize Carrierwave further.

Comment: Ok, I changed the form to f.file_field and the error message it now gives after not saving the photo upload is "Profile photo can't be blank." So it isn't saving that once I hit the save button.

Comment: I do already have it in my strong params. I'll add that to the post for clarity. Could it have anything to do with nested routing?

Comment: After looking it over I believe the model should be Pet and not ProfilePhoto.  See my update at the beginning.

Comment: Haha, good save. Is the Application Controller missing anything?

Comment: I haven't used ApplicationController for Carrierwave.  It's not required.